# Electron tray: libappindicator-WARNING : Using '/tmp' paths in SNAP environment will lead to unreadable resources

Tags: electron

I have a simple Electron app that should live in the tray. But on running it, I get the following warning:

```
(electron:5080): libappindicator-WARNING **: 23:21:11.078: Using '/tmp' paths in SNAP environment will lead to unreadable resources
```

This warning is probably due to the use or configuration of the `iconPath` the way I have. **What does this warning ^ mean and what needs to be done to remove it?**

This is my app's source:

```
const { app, Tray, Notification, Menu, nativeImage } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'assets/icons/iconTemplate.png');

let tray = null;

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    try {
        console.log(iconPath);
        tray = new Tray(nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath));
        tray.setToolTip('Electron app');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```